# imap_open failed in my server but works in local

Tags: php, imap

```
$mailboxes =
            array(
                'label' => 'Mail',
                'mailbox' => '{mail.example.com:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX',
                'username' => "myadress@mail.com",
                'password' => "mypassword"
           );

imap_open($mailboxes['mailbox'], $mailboxes['username'], $mailboxes['password'])
```

I have caught this error when I use `imap_last_error()` :

> "Connection failed to mail.example.com,143: Connection timed out"

But when I have tried it in localhost (Wampserveur), everything works fine.

Note: `extension=php_imap.dll` is enable on my serveur.

Comment: Yes, but are the ports fire walled off?  This is common.  Log in with ssh and try telnetting to the server.

Comment: Indeed it was this thanks !